# javascript/node.js intellisense in visual studio 2013/resharper problematic

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, resharper, ntvs

Visual Studio 2013 with:

- Resharper 8.2
- Node.js tools
- Web essentials

From what I gather from the [node.js tools site](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/), I should be getting intellisense.

However when editing javascript in a node.js project I get strange intellisense which suggests all sort of irrelevant stuff. It doesn't have any useful intellisense for node, and does things like autocompletes `require` as `required` which is extremely annoying as I have to hit escape to stop it from changing it, I sometimes miss it and this causes a runtime error.

It gives me intellisense for my own code within the project, but very little else.

I read this, with some hope:

https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/workitem/562

However, if I disable Resharper intellisense for js files, rather than it deferring to Visual Studio/node.js tools I get no intellisense at all. I'm doing this at the moment because nothing is better than having the `require` -> `required` issue.

Have been unable to find anything useful in Google or on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you disable ReSharper's code completion, you also need to make sure Visual Studio's is enabled. Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Node.js and look for the "Statement completion" check boxes.

Comment: It wasn't quite there, but it put me on the right track - it was under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript -> Auto List Members.

Thanks!